# Make D3 version 5 map ocean like D3 version 3 map ocean

Tags: javascript, d3.js

How do I make the ocean area keep a white background with d3.js version 5? I am using what is in [this](https://bl.ocks.org/MariellaCC/0055298b94fcf2c16940) bl.ocks.org page but with a different version. She is using version 3 and I am using version 5. I have two pages, one using version 3 [here](http://z1labs.com/projects/d3/map-d3v3.html) and one using version 5 [here](http://z1labs.com/projects/d3/map-d3v5.html). The CSS and HTML are the same for both. Only difference is the D3 version. How do I make the version 5 ocean part look like that of version 3 where the ocean part is white? Thank you.

Here is what my css and js is set to for the maps.

```
<style type="text/css">

            svg {
                background-color: white;
            }

            h1 {
                color: rgb(115, 115, 115);
                font-size: 18px;
                font-family: sans-serif;
                font-weight: bold;
                margin: 0;
                padding-bottom: 10px;

            }

            #container {
                width: 90%;
                margin-left: auto;
                margin-right: auto;
                margin-top: 20px;
                padding: 20px;
                background-color: white;
                box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 2px rgb(217, 217, 217);
            }

            path:hover {
                fill: rgba(157, 197, 243, 0.911);
                cursor:pointer;
            }



        </style>
    </head>
    <body>


    <div id="container">

    </div>
        

        <script type="text/javascript">



            //Width and height
            var w = 800;
            var h = 600;

            //Define map projection


            var projection = d3.geoMercator() //utiliser une projection standard pour aplatir les pôles, voir D3 projection plugin
                                   .center([ 23, 42 ]) //comment centrer la carte, longitude, latitude
                                   .translate([ w/2, h/2 ]) // centrer l'image obtenue dans le svg
                                   .scale([ w/1.5 ]); // zoom, plus la valeur est petit plus le zoom est gros 

            //Define path generator
            var path = d3.geoPath()
                             .projection(projection);


            //Create SVG
            var svg = d3.select("#container")
                        .append("svg")
                        .attr("width", w)
                        .attr("height", h);

            //Load in GeoJSON data
            d3.json("data/ne_50m_admin_0_countries_simplified.json").then( function(json) {
                
                //Bind data and create one path per GeoJSON feature
                svg.selectAll("path")
                   .data(json.features)
                   .enter()
                   .append("path")
                   .attr("d", path)
                   .attr("stroke", "rgba(8, 81, 156, 0.2)")
                   .attr("fill", "rgba(8, 81, 156, 0.6)");
        
            });


        
        </script>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're working with svg's & paths, targeting the ocean with css selectors and not effecting other things without adding an id or class to it specifically will be very impractical (theoretically you could see if it maintains the same position in the svg group [x] and target it with a :nth-child(x) selector, then overwrite the :hover fill property, but doesn't seem like the best way)

It already has a different color though so it's clearly being effecting alone at some point. I would try to find where it's altered in the JS and see if there's an option you could pass for the ocean. The d3 .geo function seems like a good place to look, as well as looking in the json you're passing in.

Potentially helpful links:

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/d3js/d3js_geographies.htm

[Change color on a map D3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36672732/change-color-on-a-map-d3)

Sorry I couldn't straight up answer it for you, but I'm new at d3 too and I'm also curious about this. If you figure out how to do this it would be much appreciated if you post your finding back here :)

EDIT: I think I found something! I'm still working on a quick setup to test it but I think doing it this way:

```
.style("stroke", (feature) => {
            if (feature.continent != "Seven seas (open ocean)"){ return "rgba(8, 81, 156, 0.2)"}
            else {return "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)"}
        })
.style("fill", (feature) => {
            if (feature.continent != "Seven seas (open ocean)"){ return "rgba(8, 81, 156, 0.6)"}
            else {return "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6)"}
        })
.classed("ocean-area", (feature) => {
            if (feature.continent != "Seven seas (open ocean)"){ return true}
            else {return false}
        });
```

instead of this way:

```
.attr("stroke", "rgba(8, 81, 156, 0.2)")
.attr("fill", "rgba(8, 81, 156, 0.6)")
```

where you are binding you're data and creating the paths, *should* work. It should filter whether the object's continent property(in the json data) is "open ocean" and return one color or the other, then do the same thing to add a class to the ocean-area and overwrite the :hover style with that CSS selector

http://www.d3noob.org/2013/01/select-items-with-if-statement-in-d3js.html

Last Edit:

I'm too awful at d3 to even get a local copy of this working :/ but comparing the example to yours I see that in the example there is actually not a fill over the ocean. Looking closer at yours I see there is a fill over the ocean as well as some landlocked spots that are part of the same fill, and so change color when hovering over the ocean with it. This leads me to think it is to do with the data being input or even just the way that data is formatted. After all day, I'm giving up though, so good luck and thanks to the next person!